# How to convert large number of PDF with data(same format) to excel in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, data-structures, terminal

I've been given 5000 pdf files with user info like name, number, address etc and I need to create a database in excel with list of users in a column and their informations in rows, Is it even possible from the terminal or simple software ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible from terminal.

You can start by converting the files to an easy to read format, like txt:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt"; done
```

For `pdftotext` you need [THIS](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/poppler-utils/)

And then you can read out the files and write it into a csv file with the proper symbols

```
cat file.txt | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > FILE.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have good solution but **`pdftotext filename.pdf`** can help you out. It'll create a file **`filename.txt`** in your directory containing extracted text from that PDF.